# Trying to call simple POST API from console App in VS2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, async-await, zendesk-api

I am trying to call simple `POST API` to create a `Zendesk` Ticket from Console App. 
I create C# core console app in `VS2019` and pasted simple code which should create New Ticket.
code work in other app but in console app, app just log out from debug...
call never goes...

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://testhelp.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json"))
    {
        try
        {
            var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test@test.com:testPassword"));
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

            request.Content = new StringContent("{\"ticket\": {\"subject\": \"My first Ticket!\", \"comment\": { \"body\": \"The ticket is from API.\" }}}");
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: _app just log out from debug_ doesn't make much sense or tell us what your seeing, please describe the behavior you see and the behavior you're looking for. As a note remember that console application will exit as soon as soon as the main ends, if you don't await your tasks and put something like `Console.ReadLine` your program will exit before all your code runs.

Comment: HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false); till this line debug is ok, but when call goes after some time App just exit.... i only created new console app and added code. i check with existing console app used for some other purpose is working fine. ticket is being created...but if i put same code in new basic console app it does not....App gets exit after above line ..never hit below breakpoint.....

Comment: @user2813740, I want to know if you only have the problem about app get exit without other exceptions. If so, you can set break point or console.readkey() to check if get the correct result. Besides, I almost run the same code with you, but I didn't meet the problem you described.

Comment: oh i create Console core App (C#) in visual studio 2019. and just pasted my code. same code work with old console app created earlier not by me. it worked...but with VS2019 new console app same code never get called API. app just get exit. do i am missing to add any reference or nuget package so that API will be called ?

Comment: Show us your main loop from the console app.

Comment: I will take your silence as an acknowledgement that you were not using awaits correctly and indeed it was just that your program quit out before the async call finished.

Comment: no actually i wasted my two days on it,,no extra code. only above code i used and copied inside function and called that function from main thats it. just created new console app in VS2019 then added above code in function and called that function from Main. nothing else.....

Comment: That is the point, my second example shows how if you turn it from  static void main to static task main you can properly await the finish of the async function so that's why I want to see your main loop.  Most main loops from default programs are not statlic task Main

Answer (score -1):

Async calls are frigid mistresses in some cases.

**A good option** is to make your main program async and therefore able to  await tasks.  The issue here is with GUI if that is what you actually have when you get away from the command line I am not sure how well it plays with UI threads, but here is the example.  Which is much more elegant.

```
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                 var  TicketTask = await createTicket();
            }
        
             async static Task<string> createTicket()
            {
                var content = "unknown error";
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://testhelp.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json"))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test@test.com:testPassword"));
                            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");
    
                            request.Content = new StringContent("{\"ticket\": {\"subject\": \"My first Ticket!\", \"comment\": { \"body\": \"The ticket is from API.\" }}}");
                            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
                            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                            //Console.WriteLine(response);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            content = ex.Message;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return content;
            }
```

**Quick-and-dirty-simple-solution** (which I would not suggest for production) is to monitor content within the main loop as a global variable where you fill it on success or failure.

```
      static string content = "";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var loopcount = 0;
            var t = new Task(createTicket);
            t.Start();
            while(content == "" && loopcount < 50000)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                loopcount++;
            }
        }
    
         async static void createTicket()
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://testhelp.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test@test.com:testPassword"));
                        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

                        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"ticket\": {\"subject\": \"My first Ticket!\", \"comment\": { \"body\": \"The ticket is from API.\" }}}");
                        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
                        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                        //Console.WriteLine(response);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        content = ex.mesage;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```