# Call simple POST API from console App in VS2019 with XML

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, http, web-services, post

I have referred the [Trying to call simple POST API from console App in VS2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62302464/trying-to-call-simple-post-api-from-console-app-in-vs2019). But, need to pass XML method in post instead of JSON . Any suggestions ?

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var TicketTask = await createTicket();
    }

    async static Task<string> createTicket()
    {
        var content = "unknown error";
        using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "http://1.0.01.1/slive/"))
            {
                try
                {
                    var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password"));
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

                  
                    request.Content =  new StringContent("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi...", Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml"); ????? need to post a xml method here 
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/xml");
                    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    Console.WriteLine(response);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    content = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
        return content;
```

Comment: If you could try asking a more specific question, and provide more detail about what you're tried, other than a large blob of code. For example, what about the code you posted *isn't* working? What errors are you getting and what have you tried already? Finally, posting a block of code this large is not helpful, since the majority of it isn't relevant at all to your question.

Comment: Sure, In the above example ( SOAP call) the body is sent in JSON format and Not XML as we do in Postman. I have created a console app in ASP.NET Core to replicate POSTMAN. Need suggestion on how can I pass XML in the body instead of JSON.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, please correct me if there is a better way:

```
async static Task<string> createTicket2()
{
    var content = "unknown error";
    using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "http://10/sap-lve/"))
        {
            try
            {
                var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("an:s"));
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

                String str1 = @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><s:Body><Get_api_version xmlns='http://e.s.a.com'/></s:Body></s:Envelope>";

                **request.Content = new StringContent(str1, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");** ;
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/xml");
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                //Console.WriteLine(response);
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(result.Result);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                content = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```